# How to make a template with customized bit shift values

Tags: c++, templates, bit-manipulation, undefined-behavior

Suppose that I need a function template that does different amounts of bit shifts on different integer types. For example, if the input value `n` is of type `char`, the function does some calculations on `n>>2` and `n<<3`. If it is `short int`, then the function uses `n>>1` and `n<<8`. For `int` type, there would be `n>>11` and `n<<9`, and so on. Of course, the values mentioned are just for example and there is no correlation between them and the size of int_type.

My suggestion for this problem was something like this:

```
template <typename Num_Type = char, int s1 = 2, int s2 = 3> void test1(Num_Type &n)
{
    // this is just an example code:
    int a = n >> s1,
        b = n << s2;
    // do some calculations on a and b
}
```

So I can use this template for different types of input value. But when I compile it, it gives me several warnings about undefined behavior in shift operations, because the value may be too big.

So the question can be asked in two forms:

1. How can I customize bit-shift operations without getting "undefined behavior" warnings? or
2. Can I have a limited data type, say `intlength` which can only have a specified range of numbers, say `0, 1, 2, ... , 31`? I know it may sound stupid, but in this case, I can define the template as

   ```
   template <typename Num_Type = char, intlength s1 = 2, intlength s2 = 3> void test1(Num_Type &n)
   ```

and so the compiler should not complain about shift values.

Comment: Why do you get the warnings? I mean, why are you trying to shift `n` with a too big `s1` or `s2`?

Comment: @rozina I am not trying to shift it with too big values, My intended values are small, but since the shift amount is of int type, the compiler thinks it may get too big

Comment: I see. Perhaps the warning is not useful here and you could disable it for this function. And to be safe you can add asserts into the function body, to test that `s1` and `s2` are not too big. [Clang does not produce any warnings though](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ad90bdc4aec37f1f)

Comment: @rozina Can you give some more details? I am not so experienced in C++ and just rely on try & error, and of course, google

Comment: And what about the second part of my question?

Comment: It is strange that your compiler issues warnings though, since `s1` and `s2` are all known at compile time.

Comment: @rozina Just a wild guess, it may be because of two-phase lookup, which is implemented in clang and not in VS. My compiler is VS

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the warning for this function with a `#pragma` command, which depends on the compiler you are using. You will have to google that yourself.

**Edit:** since you mention you are using VisualStudio, [here is a link to disable warnings. :)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/441722ys.aspx)

Once you disable the warning you can add a `static_assert` to check if `s1` and `s2` are in range of the `Num_Type`. Although I find it strange that your compiler does not do that itself since everything is known at compile time.

```
template <typename Num_Type, int s1 = 2, int s2 = 3> void test1(Num_Type &n)
{    
    constexpr auto max = sizeof(Num_Type) * 8;
    static_assert(s1 < max && s2 < max, "integer overflow");

    // this is just an example code:
    int a = n >> s1,
        b = n << s2;
}
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2c3df573b2ad05a7)

Answer (score 0):

The healthy way to change template function behavior depending on input type is to use template specialization. For example:

```
template <typename num_t> test(num_t n);
template <> test<int> (num_t n){
    int shift_amount = 4;
    // do shifts
}
template <> test<char> (num_t n){
    int shift_amount = 1;
    // do shifts
}
```

Also, make sure to surround your shifts with if checks to make sure there is no overflow.

Comment: This doesn't make a difference

Answer (score 0):

I see no need for templates. All you need is simple overloading:

```
auto test(char n) { ... }
auto test(uint16_t n) { .. }
auto test(uint32_t n) { .. }
```

Comment: I know that. My goal is not to "solve" a problem. I want to know how to do something

Comment: And if the code is very big, overloading the function will be a pain in the butt

Comment: Then I don't understand your question. I don't understand what you want.